# How to recover data of a Bluescreen XEN HVM Windows server (SolusVM)?

Tags: windows, vps, xen, solusvm, hvm

The server won't boot into any of the following modes and the VPS crashes in the loading screen with a Bluescreen error.

```
SafeMode
SafeMode with Networking
Last Known Good Configuration
Normally
```

How do I troubleshoot and recover the files from the VPS Image file?

Comment: Attach new Hard disk to the vm and also attach windows iso. then perform os installation on the new hard disk and once the installation is complete try booting into new installation and backup your data.

Comment: I was about to answer my own question and you ruined it :P.

Comment: Lol..I have done similar things but in Virtualizor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many answers in the web which all points to mounting a recovery disc and repairing the Operating System of the Virtual hard disk. But this method is not guaranteed to work at all times.

My approach on retrieving the files from this dead VM is something more clear and it is recommended for SolusVM users. The method is to install an alternative Windows Operating system in a new partition which helps you to access the files of your dead image partition.

1. Shutdown your Virtual Machine (VM).
2. Use the Resources button in the SolusVM manage panel and add additional 30GB disk space to your VM.
3. Copy a Windows server ISO to the following folder.

   /home/solusvm/xen/iso/
4. Add the ISO in the SolusVM Menu: `Media` and select `Add ISO`.
5. After adding the ISO mount the ISO on your VM using the CD ROM mounting option.
6. Now change the boot order of VM to the following.

   CD ROM(1),Hard Disk(2).
7. Now boot your VM and immediately attempt and connect to your VNC.
8. Press any key to Boot from CD.
9. Choose `Install Now` and Accept the terms.
10. Choose custom installation and in the next window, your unallocated 30GB will be displayed where you can format and install your Windows server.
11. Complete installation and access using the Windows File Explorer to find the Disk partition of your dead VPS as Local disks.
12. Now you can move your Valuable data to a new VPS.

I hope this solution will help those who had faced this issue.